# Multiset/Multinomial - Dividing Students into Teams

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Question: I have 15 students and wish to divide them into three study teams of five students each. In how many ways can I do this?

Is this not $\binom{15}{5,5,5}$, or am I missing something?

I've taken a look at [Multinomial Theorem Example Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365643/multinomial-theorem-example-questions), but I honestly still can't really understand the difference between the examples in that one, and whether or not I should use one option or the other.

Comment: Is each team studying a different topic, or are all teams studying the same topic? In the former case the different topics correspond to the uniforms in André’s answer, and you get $\binom{15}{5,5,5}$. In the latter case the ‘uniforms’ disappear, and $\binom{15}{5,5,5}$ counts each division $3!$ times, once for each of the $3!$ possible assignments of different topics (if there had been different topics).

Comment: In that case it’s probably the second interpretation, and you want $\frac1{3!}\binom{15}{5,5,5}$: each of the three groups is studying the same material, so there’s nothing analogous to the uniforms in André’s example — nothing that distinguishes the teams except their actual composition.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still not sure why that works, so I'll keep re-reading Andre's post. I just don't get why they're being over-counted because of the non-distinguishing nature.

Comment: Maybe an extreme example would help. Suppose that you have $3$ students, $A,B$, and $C$, and you want to divide them into teams of $1$. Obviously the teams have to be $\{A\},\{B\}$, and $\{C\}$: there’s only one way to do it. Now suppose, though, that one team is to study chemistry, another German, and a third calculus. Now there are $\binom{3}{1,1,1}=6$ ways to make the division: there are $\binom31$ ways to choose a student for the chemistry team, then there are $\binom21$ ways to choose one of the remaining students for the German team, and finally there are $\binom11$ ways to finish up.

Comment: That actually does help. But I'm having trouble reconciling that with an example from my text: " In how many ways can we distribute ten books to three students, so that one student receives two books, one receives three, and one receives five?" That answer is apparently $\binom{10}{2,3,5}$. How does that work given your example differences?

Comment: That’s because each book and each student has a separate identity. If the books were indistinguishable, we’d be overcounting badly, and there would be only $6$ ways: $3$ ways to choose who gets two books, then $2$ to choose who gets $3$, and the remaining person gets $5$.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I just wasn't making that connection. Everything makes much more sense now.

Comment: You’re very welcome; glad to help!